# Android Error: Failure getting entry for 0x010802c0 (t=7 e=704) in package 0 (error -75)

Tags: javascript, android, html, geolocation

I am receiving the error:

```
09-20 17:19:34.823: W/ResourceType(25329): Failure getting entry for 0x010802c0 (t=7 e=704) in package 0 (error -75)
```

When I click on the button "Get Location".

My code is as follows:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
    <title>Taxi Friends</title>



    <script type="text/javascript">


    function getLocation(){
        if(!navigator.geolocation){
            alert("your browser doesn't support geolocation");
        }
        else {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success,error,enableHighAccuracy = true);
        }
    }

        function success(position){
            var lat = position.coords.latitude;
            var lng = position.coords.longitude;

            alert(lat + ', ' + lng);
        }

        function error(error){
         switch (error.code) {
                case error.PERMISSION_DENIED: alert("user did not share geolocation data");
                    break;
                case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE: alert("could not detect current position");
                    break;
                case error.TIMEOUT: alert("retrieving position timed out");
                    break;
                default: alert("unknown error");
                    break;
            }
            //alert('sorry error occurred');
        }



    </script>
</head>

<body style="background-color:#FF9900;">
    <input id="getLocation" type="button" value="Get Location" onclick="getLocation();" />


</body>
```

On my phone (Samsung Galaxy S2) I receive an alert saying "could not detect current position". I am also using PhoneGap.

Would anyone know what this may refer to?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hey did you find solution for this ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't.. This was for a uni project. Ended up doing something else. Good luck with it.